# How to escape percent symbol when using it as a command in a FOR loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use de git log command result as input to for loop, but seems impossible! I already tried to use %%, ^%, %%%, ^%^%, enableDelayedExpansion and others:

```
@echo off
for /f %%s in ('git log --reverse --format=%h') do (
  echo git pull
  echo git reset --hard %%s
  pause
)
```

The git command I need is: `git log --reverse --format=%h`

The problem is that "%h" is not working inner the for. When I use `git log --reverse`, for example, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f %%s in ('git log --reverse --format^=%%h') do (
```

should cure your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a format variable

```
set "format=--format=%%h"
for /f %%s in ('git log --reverse %%format%%') do (
```

This way it even works with more complex formats like `%cd%H` ( committer date and hash)

```
set "format=--format=%%cd%%H"
for /f %%s in ('git log --reverse %%format%%') do (
```